# How to build a Vaadin demo sampler type of page

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a simple question, I am trying to build something similar to whats in this URL
   Visit: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6

Specifically, I want to know how to create those boxes , which can be clicked on ? I am not           sure what these are? whether they are links or images or buttons?

I also what the box around it when a mouse is moved over these boxes. Any sample code is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with or without the Vaadin framework?

Comment: To me, it's not entirely clear what you're asking for. There's many ways to replicate that, but it depends on what your needs are, and what existing technologies you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The sampler page is created with Vaadin. According to FireBug it's made with a CSSLayout and those boxes are made with links. The hover effect is made with the following css attribute:

```
.v-csslayout-grid .screenshot a:hover span {
    background: url("screenshot-frame-hover.png") no-repeat scroll 1px 0px transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code for a "relatively" recent version of the Vaadin 6 Sampler [here](https://vaadin.com/downloading?package=demo/sampler/current/sampler.war).

At least this version (which I believe to be 6.7.4) should give you some examples of what you're looking for.